# run a docker-compose from crontab

Tags: django, docker-compose, cron

I have a command

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-deploy.yml run --rm app sh -c "python manage.py runcrons"
```

that works if I run it from terminal. Now I want to run this command from a crontab but I am a bit at a loss of how I should write this. I have tried a bunch of things based on things I have found here:

*/5 * * * * cd /home/ec2-user/legend-of-solgard; docker-compose -f docker-compose-deploy.yml run --rm app sh -c "python manage runcrons”

*/5 * * * *  /usr/bin/docker-compose -f /home/ec2-user/legend-of-solgard/docker-compose-deploy.yml exec -T app run --rm app sh -c "python manage runcrons”

But nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure on what you're trying to do but Ofelia might be able to do what you want to do. It's kinda similar to cron, as you can specify a schedule for a command inside the docker-compose file, I have it configured like this:

```
ofelia:
    image: mcuadros/ofelia:latest
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    depends_on:
      - backend
    command: daemon --docker
    labels:
      - ofelia.job-exec.enable=true
      - ofelia.job-exec.backend.schedule=0 0,20,40 7-23 * * *
      - ofelia.job-exec.backend.command=python /home/app/web/manage.py runcrons
      - ofelia.job-exec.backend.container=backend
```

Also checkout the docs over here: https://github.com/mcuadros/ofelia

Ofcourse you can change the schedule to whatever you like